# Error loading apt-installed QtDataVisualization at runtime on ubuntu

Tags: qt, qml, ubuntu-20.04, qtdatavisualization

I'm running Qt 5.12 on ubuntu 20.04.3. Qt software components are installed with apt. My C++ application uses Qt DataVisualization . I've installed these apt packages for DataVisualization:

```
libqt5datavisualization5-dev
qml-module-qtdatavisualization
```

The app compiles OK, but the runtime cannot find the qml module. My qml file contains this import statement as [specified by Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-index.html):

```
import QtDataVisualization 1.15
```

But at runtime I get the error:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:6 module "QtDataVisualization" version 1.15 is not installed
```

I get a similar runtime error if qml has "import QtDataVisualization 1.14".
Can someone help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This page indicates that DataVisualization 1.2 should be imported for Qt 5.12 applications](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.12/qtdatavisualization-index.html) - this resolves my issue.